# what does rack provide to each in its middleware

Tags: ruby, rack

I saw the following code posted on railscasts:

```
def each(&block)
    block.call("<!-- #{@message}: #{@stop - @start} -->\n") if @headers["Content-Type"].include? "text/html"
    @response.each(&block)
  end
```

I was wondering where the &block was coming from? What's happening here?

Comment: Can you add more information? Like the screnncastor at least a bigger chunk of code to get some context.

Comment: That's not actually a rack thing but middleware code, defined and used within the middleware context.

Comment: It's from here http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware

Comment: Just saw the video @Cenoc . Rack will call each over the response body (the third element of the response array). Ryan is returning self as the body and defining each on it so it became Rack compatible. I don't like it at all but it's what he is doing.

Answer (score 1):

`&block` is the way to define a method in Ruby that accepts a method and to explicitly assign the block to the variable referenced by the `&`.

Specifically, what that code does, it to accept a block, call the block passing a string as argument, then passing the block to the inner response.

At first glance, I would say that the specific middleware you saw is basically injecting the string

```
"<!-- #{@message}: #{@stop - @start} -->\n"
```

into the HTTP response body if the request content type is `"text/html"`, which means an HTTP page.

If the request is for an HTTP page, than the response is served and that string is injected. Otherwise, if the request is for another kind of file (for instance a binary file, a text file, a javascript, etc), then the response is served without any modification.

The following example will help you to understand a little bit more the scope of `&block`

```
def foo(&block)
  puts "foo"
  bar(&block)
end

def bar(&block)
  puts "bar"
  block.call
end

foo do
  puts "block"
end

# => foo
# => bar
# => block
```

Also note that the variable holding the block can be named anything, not necessary `block`

```
def foo(&my_block)
  puts "foo"
  bar(&my_block)
end

def bar(&another_block)
  puts "bar"
  another_block.call
end

foo do
  puts "block"
end

# => foo
# => bar
# => block
```

Comment: I'm specifically asking about this one use case shown in http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware ; many thanks for the help!

Comment: My answer explains the code. The middleware is injecting the time in the response if this is an HTML page.

Comment: Well, I understand your example, what I don't understand is what the call to block in `block.call` is achieving or what is being passed as block to `each` (seemingly by rack?)

Answer (score 0):

On the given example `each` is defined to make the middleware behaves as a valid ***rack*** response body too (I really don't recommend that).

Rack expect the response body to be an instance of a class that defines `each` as a public method (an **Array** or even an **ActionController::Response** instance).

Any middleware after that one may use that `each` to operate over the response body. At the end of the middlewares chain rack itself will use it to process and dispatch the final response.